# Electromagnetic waves of accelerating charges

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Is it true that more accelerating a charge will cause electromagnetic waves of more energy than the energy of the electromagnetic waves cause by lesser accelerated charge ?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to look at this is with [Larmor's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula), which gives the power radiated by an accelerated charged particle. 
$$ P = \frac{q^2 a^2}{6\pi \epsilon_0 c^3},$$
where $a$ is the magnitude of the acceleration.

So the short answer is yes, it is true.